# Django - Multiple optional ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, validation, model, foreign-keys

```
class Truc(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  machin1 = models.ForeignKey(Machin1, blank=True, null=True)
  machin2 = models.ForeignKey(Machin2, blank=True, null=True)
  machin3 = models.ForeignKey(Machin3, blank=True, null=True)
```

I would like `Truc` to be linked to one `machin`, either `machin1` either `machin2` or `machin3`.

Only one link, so this kind of validation:

```
machin1 xor machin2 xor machin3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only ever linked to one use a [generic relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations):

```
class Truc(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    machin_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Comment: Ok, it's doing what I was searching for, but I think I should design my `Machin` objects differently. I think they should simply point (multi2multi) to `Truc`